# SQL working with dates in where clause

Tags: sql, inner-join, where-clause

I have this SQL code here..

```
SELECT cl.clientid,
       cl.clientname,
       cl.billingdate,
       cp.startdate,
       cp.expiration, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM invoice 
            HERE client = cl.clientid) AS invoicecount  
FROM client cl
INNER JOIN clientplan cp ON cp.client = cl.clientid
WHERE cl.isbilled = 1 AND expiration is NULL AND expiration > '2012-06-22'
```

My problem is that a client could have 3 client plans and they either have an expiration date or the expiration is NULL. I am trying to get the rows that are not expired or are NULL.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the date is NULL, you will never have a value.. [edit] so it will either be EXPIRATION IS NULL OR (EXPIRATION IS NOT NULL AND EXPIRATION > '22-JUN-2012') [/edit]

Comment: `AND` doesn't mean `these records and those records` it means `where this is true and that is true`.  In your case you *can't* have `expiration IS NULL` ***and*** `expiration > '2012-06-22'` both being true at the same time.  You mean `cl.isbilled = 1 AND (expiration is NULL OR expiration > '2012-06-22')`

Comment: As a side note, its probably worth adding in your sql implementations version of todays date. forexample in postgres its now()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure, but isn't what you want this :

```
SELECT cl.clientid, cl.clientname, cl.billingdate, cp.startdate, cp.expiration, 
(select count(*) from invoice where client = cl.clientid) as invoicecount  
FROM client cl
inner join clientplan cp on cp.client = cl.clientid
where cl.isbilled = 1 and (expiration is NULL or expiration > '2012-06-22')
```

With an or instead of an and on the expirations. Because expiration cannot be null and > '2012-06-22'...